# XSLT - result of foreach in same line

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem processing an xml file with xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<center name="center" code="11111" version="1.0">
<teachers>
    <teacher>
      <name>My name</name>
      <surname>My surname</surname>
      <groupsubject>2CFSA#2CFS0653</groupsubject>
      <groupsubject>2CFSA#2CFS0655</groupsubject>
      <groupsubject>1CFSA#1CFS0647</groupsubject>
      <groupsubject>1CFSA#1CFS0648</groupsubject>
    </teacher>
<teachers>
</center>
```

I want to create a CSV file with all this data, for each teacher: name,surname,group1,group2,group3,...,groupN
This is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="teachers">
        <xsl:for-each select="teacher">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>,<xsl:value-of select="surname"/>,
            <xsl:for-each select="groupsubject">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that the foreach sentence creates a new file for each groupsubject, instead of add the content to the same line. I know this is correct, but I can't know how can extract all the teacher data in only one line (csv line).
Anyone can help me?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carriage returns in your XSLT, after the commas, are being literally interpreted. Use the `<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>` to prevent this.
ie.

```
 <xsl:template match="teachers">
    <xsl:for-each select="teacher">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="surname"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="groupsubject">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```